# Read write categories from form

Tags: php, sql, forms, insert

I have low hopes of somebody actually answering that cause of the high level of spoon feeding involved ;-) But then again, I ll give it a shot.

I would like to make a simple form consisting of an input text field, a dropdown list of existing categories and a submit button. The logic would be:

Case 1: User inputs text to the input field and clicks submit. Then code checks if text equals name of existing category. If category name exists then nothing is done and code prompts user that this category exists. If category name does not exist then the entered text is being written in the database as a new category.

Case 2: User leaves input field empty and selects a category from dropdown list of existing categories. Then upon clicking submit, the code would store the category name selected from the dropdown in a variable.

Case 3: User clicks submit without entering any text or selecting any category from dropdown, then code does nothing and prompts for user to retry..

Any help, code or link, would be much appreciated.

Harry

Comment: Dear please google it. try to code and just ask here you gonna get solution. i dont think any body going to reply you with the answer.

Comment: case 2: can you please elaborate why you want it to store it in variable ?

Comment: I will be using this variable later on when the form becomes more complicated with several input fields defining a complete "item" in the database..

Comment: Arif, you did reply though didnt you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is a relatively easy task. Even when you are new to programming, this should be possible. What you want is a form validation.

I would recommend to call a function on submit like that:
onsubmit='checkForm()'
Put this code in your form tag.

In that function you can check what ever you want to make sure that the form works the way you want it.

You should read this:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: Marcus, thanks a lot for the tip.. Sometimes when you are completely newbie to something you dont even know how to google for it.. Form validation was the key here.. I know where to begin now..